# Where are the SQL connection and queries implemented in Laravel?

Tags: laravel

I wonder where all of that SQL queries are located which provide database connection, data manupilation and others. I tried to dive deeper and deeper into Laravel source code but all I found is just Laravel methods. I know this is very useless but is also very interesting to know.

Comment: There are bo complete queries somewhere. They are built on demand by using Eloquent or query builder methods.

Answer (score 1):

### Where is the Connection [made]?

You shouldn't have to mess with the SQL directly. That is a feature of Laravel.  If you are curious thoug, the Database connection is in (if you haven't published your vender files) `/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/DataBaseManger.php` in make connection starting at line 101 where we have a call:

```
return $this->factory->make($config, $name);
```

Which calls:

```
return $this->createSingleConnection($config);
```

Which does:

```
    $pdo = $this->createPdoResolver($config);

    return $this->createConnection(
        $config['driver'], $pdo, $config['database'], $config['prefix'], $config
    );
```

So we have a $pdo object being passed to createConnection which does:

```
return new MySqlConnector;
```

Which does the connection:

```
   public function connect(array $config)
{
    $dsn = $this->getDsn($config);

    $options = $this->getOptions($config);

    // We need to grab the PDO options that should be used while making the brand
    // new connection instance. The PDO options control various aspects of the
    // connection's behavior, and some might be specified by the developers.
    $connection = $this->createConnection($dsn, $config, $options);

    if (! empty($config['database'])) {
        $connection->exec("use `{$config['database']}`;");
    }

    $this->configureEncoding($connection, $config);

    // Next, we will check to see if a timezone has been specified in this config
    // and if it has we will issue a statement to modify the timezone with the
    // database. Setting this DB timezone is an optional configuration item.
    $this->configureTimezone($connection, $config);

    $this->setModes($connection, $config);

    return $connection;
}
```

But why is that so convoluted and complicated?  Because, you can do complex things like having a "connection" that uses one database for read and another for write, or switching to a different type of database (maybe a non-relational database) and not have to worry about changing all your code.

### And Queries Implimeneted

There are two places.  Illuminate has the Database Query Builder and Eloquent has the ORM (which uses the QueryBuilder under the hood I believe.  But the execution happens in `Illuminate/Query/Builder` get() calls the protected method runSelect() which calls the `$this->connection->select(...)` which executes the built PDO statement on line 330 of `Illuminate/Database/Connection`.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. I finally found all of these reference to PHPStorm Stubs - PDO.php file. But the methods in this file have empty body. For example,

`public function execute ($input_parameters = null) {}`

Now the main question is that how this works.

Comment: PHPStorm's stubs are not the actual implementation. They're just so PHPStorm can show you the arguments etc. The actual implementation for that function is part of PHP itself: https://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.execute.php

Comment: https://github.com/JetBrains/phpstorm-stubs STUBS are normal, syntactically correct PHP files that contain function & class signatures, constant definitions, etc. for all built-in PHP stuff and most standard extensions. Stubs need to include complete PHPDOC, especially proper @return annotations.

An IDE needs them for completion, code inspection, type inference, doc popups, etc. Quality of most of these services depend on the quality of the stubs (basically their PHPDOC @annotations).

Answer (score 0):

The SQL connection is in .env file in the root directory of your project.If you want to override the connection from .env then you can set in `config > database.php` inside the project root directory.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to see how the queries are built, just look for the file `Builder.php` located on `vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Database\Query` folder.

Then you can check all other files in the `Query` folder to see what's happening on your eloquent queries.

> You will never have to touch those files, just use the
>   [documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/queries) to know how to use the Query Builder.

Comment: Not to touch, only looking at. All I want is to understand the underlying processes. As I wrote in the above comment, all of these reference to Stubs file -PDO.php